# Custom bootloader not working

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader

I have designed my custom bootloader (which showy my name only.) using assembly language and compiled it using NASM. Now I want to install it in USB.But not able to find any way for burning it. I have tested using different utilities like ISOtoUSB, Universal USB,rufus. Error is coming 'image is not bootable.'

But when I run the same on oracle virtual drive, it works perfectly.

I am doing some college project and strucked, I want to load that bootloader to usb and when I boot from usb, my bootloader should work.

Any idea please?

Here is my code:

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7C00]

main:
mov ax, 0x0000
mov ds,ax

mov si, string
call print
jmp $

print:
mov ah,0x0E
mov bh,0x00

.nextchar
lodsb
or al,al
jz .return
int 0x10
jmp .nextchar
.return
ret
string db 'Welcome to the Amul Bhatia Operating System Now Installing....',0
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0AA55h
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you forgot to include the boot signature, hard to tell if you don't show code. See? You forgot it.

Comment: @Jester - Just added the code, can you check now.. i

Comment: Yes, I have, you did not include the required boot signature of `55 AA` at the end of your sector.

Comment: I appreciate it, if you could help ..How to add 55 AA, i followed one tutorial on youtube.. I have no idea of it,,

Comment: `times 510-($-$$) db 0; dw 0xAA55`

Comment: Still same, i added        dw 0AA55h   , and then used ISO to USB and burned it, I noticed one things, when i burn it.. the size of the usb does not change and it does not contain any files also..

Comment: Did you change 512 to 510? Also, this is a boot sector, it won't show up as a file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134301/discussion-between-aman-and-jester).

Comment: I have a solution for you... I'll link another answer.

Comment: It's likely your problem is with either how you're copying your bootsector to  your USB drive or how you're trying to boot your USB drive. Note that utilities that are meant to "burn" bootable ISO format images to USB drives won't work, because your code isn't a bootable ISO format image. These utilities modify the format of the ISO so that it can be booted on USB drives. Notably these utilities will install there own bootsector. You need a copy your bootsector to the USB drive directly.

Comment: @RossRidge - Thanks dude..you have given me clue and i tried linux command "dd if=~/Applications/boot.bin of=/dev/sdb" and got success..can you update your response as answer..???? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your bootloader, except this:

```
times 512-($-$$) db 0
```

Replace by:

```
times 510-($-$$) db 0
```

The way you are doing, your bootloader will be 514 bytes instead of 512. ;-)

[image: This is your bootloader running]

Comment: I rectified to 510 and tried to burn the same on USB. still not able to execute as bootloader

Comment: you are doing something else... your bootloader is fine and running with 510 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Even with the signature in place, you may find that some hardware will not boot your image.  It seems that some BIOS implementations *require* a valid BPB (BIOS Parameter Block) to be present in your image.

You might consider replacing the first few lines of your boot loader with something like this:

```
bits 16

org 0                                   ; BIOS will load the MBR to this location.

bootStart:
                jmp             _start
                nop
                bootDrive       db      'MSDOS6.0'
                bpb
                bps                     dw      512
                spc                     db      8
                rs                      dw      1
                fats            db      2
                re                      dw      512
                ss                      dw      0
                media           db      0xf8
                spfat           dw      0xc900
                spt                     dw      0x3f00
                heads           dw      0x1000
                hidden          dw      0x3f00, 0
                ls                      dw      0x5142,0x0600
                pdn                     db      0x80
                cheads                  db      0
                sig                     db      0x29
                serialno        dw      0xce13, 0x4630
                label           db      'NO NAME'
                fattype         db      "FAT32"

_start:
                                                        ; set up the registers
                mov     ax, 0x07c0
                mov     ds, ax
```

Comment: I have replaced my code with yours, and tried to burn the iso file (generated from bin) to USB.. No success.

Comment: The system that you are booting on... Is it an EFI system?  If it is, do you have CSM enabled?

Comment: And, of course, this isn't complete... this is simply showing the structure of the BPB... you would still need all of your boot code plus the MBR signature at the end.

Comment: Ohh , can you give me an complete example code for boot loader working on USB, mine works perfectly on oracle virtual box..and system is not EFI system